# How do I unfold brackets using vim command with sed? - Sed Replace character with newline unless first character issue

Tags: bash, vim, sed

I've got this config file that I'd like to unfold it's brackets from.
As far as I can tell I can best use the `vim -e -c 'stuff goes here'` command for this and put that inside a shell script.

*Input file*

```
["12000xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx12000",["127.0.0.1:12000"]]
```

It should look like this.

*Desired output*

```
[
"12000xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx12000",
[
"127.0.0.1:12000"
]
]
```

Well actually, that's just the first step, but I've got those mostly figured out using `gg=G`.

This command used when testing in vim itself:

```
:%s/^\[/\[\r/|%s/[^^]\[/\r\[\r/g|%s/\]/\r\]/g
```

And below is what I get to see

Output file

```
[
"12000xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx12000"
[
"127.0.0.1:12000"
]
]
```

My main issue right now is that my bracket replacement sed command replaces two characters instead of one. I figured that the `s/[^^]\[/\r\[\r/g` part of my code is wrong.

It looks at a pattern of two characters, a first character should not be the first character of the line and a second character should be an opening bracket.

That's however not what I want. I just want to look at opening brackets and only replace them if they are not the first character.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `sed` may work

```
$ sed s'/\[\([^][]*\)/[\n\1\n/g;s/]/&\n/' input_file
[
"12000xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx12000",
[
"127.0.0.1:12000"
]
]
```

Or `vim`

```
:s/\[\([^][]*\)/[\r\1\r/g|s/]/&\r/
```

Comment: Thanks. For those wondering what the vim -e -c command should be vim -e file -c ":s/\[\([^][]*\)/[\\r\1\\r/g|s/]/&\\r/" -c "wq!"

Comment: Can you also explain how it works? I thought % was necessary before s if you want to use regular expressions such as a caret, asterisk and ampersand symbols in them.

Comment: @Folaht You can also use `%` if that is your preferred syntax, but it is not necessary.  You could also have used `vim -c ':s/[([^][]*)/[\\r\1\\r/g|s/]/&\\r/' file` which would take you into the file to see the changes before committed. If happy, you can save and exit with `:x` or `:wq` as included in your code. It works by storing everything between the brackets in the hold buffer (parenthesis) and returns it with back reference `\1` between 2 new lines `g`lobally.

Comment: I guess I'll have to read up on https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html. Some of your stuff was completely new to me.

Comment: @Folaht This may be more useful https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html